# Space instead enter

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I try to simulate pressing key ENTER. But when I try to do it I have the same result like I pressed SPACE. And I don't understand why it happens.
My code:

```
field.clear().click().sendKeys("Hello");
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
```

I tryed:

```
field.clear().click().sendKeys("Hello"+"\n");
field.sendKeys("Hello",protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
```

But I always have the same result. Then I do it manually it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `RETURN` instead:

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.RETURN).perform();
```

A *new-line character* can also be an option here:

```
field.clear().click().sendKeys("Hello" + "\n");
```